# $L_1$ function which is unbounded on any set of positive, finite measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Someone recently claimed the following: if $g \in L_1(X)$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $E$ with $m(E)<\infty$, $\sup_E(|g|)<\infty$, and $\int_{E^c} |g| < \epsilon$

I am fairly certain that this is false, but I am unable to construct a counterexample.

In particular, I would like a $g\in L_1$, with (essential) $\sup_E(|g|)=\infty$ on every $E$ with $0<m(E)<\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no $g$ of the sort you describe in the third paragraph. You don't tell us what $X$ is, but suppose it's $[0,1].$ Let $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be any measurable function. Set $E_n = \{x\in [0,1]: |g(x)| < n\}.$ Then each $E_n$ is measurable, and $\cup E_n = [0,1].$ Therefore some $E_n$ has positive measure, and thus we have found a set of positive measure where $g$ is bounded.

The statement in your first paragraph is true. Keeping to the set up above, show $g\cdot \chi_{E_n} \to g$ in $L^1.$ That gives the conclusion in that setting.

Comment: sorry, but that's not what I want. I want $f$ to be unbounded on every positive, finite measure set.

Comment: @Amu I don't understand your comment. There is no such function. That is what I'm showing.

Comment: There is no such function if the measure space is *finite*.

Comment: @Amu The first paragraph of my solution works in any measure space.

Comment: But $E_n$ need not have finite measure in that case.

Comment: @Amu Find $n$ such that $E_n$ has positive measure, and then consider $E_n = \cup_m (E_n \cap [-m,m]).$